# Excel - Extracting multiple matches into separate rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hello I am trying to extract the matches (Item2) for the Item1 column into separate rows, so I have a head with the Item1, and then under it all the matches for this Item1 with the column Item2 . Please see in the picture what I am trying to achieve as well as the formula I am using which unfortunately is not properly working. Any help on that regard?

[image: Item componenents under item number]

thanks for your time

Comment: please post also desired output besides failed formula output. Without that it's impossible to understand your issue.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer , the desired output is in the Image file I attach,from D2 to D10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just want to skip the first description on `Item2` as it's more of a genereal item1 description?

If so, you can use `SMALL` and just add a `+1` to it's nth smallest value. Example:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$11=$D$1,ROW($A$1:$A$11),""),ROW(A1)+1)),"")
```

You would have to enter this as array formula through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, and drag down.

Edit:

If your data is nicely ordered in the sense that the items2 are contiguous for each item1, a non-array entered solution could be (`D2`):

```
=IF(INDEX(A:A,MATCH($D$1,A:A,0)+ROW(A1))=$D$1,INDEX(B:B,MATCH($D$1,A:A,0)+ROW(A1)),"")
```

Comment: Thanks very very much! I ended up using the non-array formula and it works just such I wanted to. When I have a bit more of time I'll try to understand it, thanks once more for your help